# How to convert date from one to another format in php?

Tags: php, datetime

I have date like "2014-05-14 19:15:00" but I want to convert it in "7:15 PM 14th May 2014".

Here is my code:

```
$start = $post['begin'];
$start='2014-05-14 19:15:00';
$start = date('l, d-M-y H:i:s T', $post['begin']);
```

but not worked for me.
How I get the desired date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format is wrong and you need a timestamp for `date()`.  To get the format `7:15 PM 14th May 2014` you will need to convert the datetime string to a timestamp and then format it correctly:

```
$start = date('g:i A jS F Y', strtotime($post['begin']));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$start=date('l, d-M-y H:i:s T',strtotime($post['begin']));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use DateTime class for date operations

```
$start='2014-05-14 19:15:00' ;
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $start);
echo $date->format('l, d-M-y H:i:s T') ;
```